# Emacs adding (prepending) ".:" to PATH in shell

Tags: macos, shell, emacs, path, rvm

I have noticed that my shell buffers in Emacs (24.3.1) have (an extra) ".:" at the beginning of the $PATH variable on my Mac OS X (but not on my linux laptop that has the same . files), compared to my regular shell, which has it in the middle somewhere.  Is this just me, or does Emacs on mac do this for some purpose?  And can I prevent it?  I don't think it has caused any actual problems, but it does cause warnings from RVM, and theoretically it has risks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `emacs` help entry for the `shell` command, the started shell gets the file `~/.emacs_SHELLNAME` or `~/.emacs.d/init_SHELLNAME.sh` as first command list (if one of those files exist). So you can modify the value of the `PATH` environment variable in one of those two files, but you should then check that your shell (configurable with the `explicit-shell-file-name` variable, the `ESHELL` environment variable or the `shell-file-name` variable, in that order) does not ignore commands that are issued during start-up.

Another reason may be that your (system-wide) configuration includes the current directory into the `PATH` value (you can check that with `echo $PATH` in a terminal), thus you would have to reconfigure your shell instead of `emacs`.

Considering security, having the current directory in the `PATH` does have the risk of unintentionally executing the wrong program (eg.: you have a self-written program named `test` and want to execute `/usr/bin/test`). That may cause some serious trouble, if that happens while working with super-user privileges.

Comment: The "security problem" might be diminished by appending the dot at the end of PATH instead of prepending it to the beginning.

Comment: @choroba: Yes, that reduces the risk to executing programs that are not installed (or not at all reachable via the `PATH` variable).

Comment: Thanks!  I don't have any ~/.emacs_* or ~/.emacs.d/init_* files.  I don't have ESHELL set.  `explicit-shell-file-name` is nil.  `shell-file-name` is "/bin/bash".   I don't think it is affected by any system-wide files - and I have made sure my regular shell does not have this.  I don't think I would ever create an executable file named 'test', and I try to avoid creating executable files that are named the same as important shared executables.  I do sometimes think I should take . out of my path, but I am an old dog, and I have had that set for many years.

Comment: I was just trying to figure out why my emacs on my Mac has that . path at the front unlike my environment elsewhere, and I use a shared set of . files.  But, thanks to your answer, I have now added a ~/.emacs_bash file to clean up the path with ``PATH=`ruby -e 'puts ENV["PATH"].split(":").reverse.uniq.reverse.join(":")'` `` which removes dups and leaves only the last one...  Which, I think is what I want.  Thanks.